# CodeBlock in TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, codeblocks, backticks

I am currently developing an Android app and I would like to incorporate a feature that allows users to input code snippets in a similar fashion to how it's done on Stack Overflow. Specifically, I would like to enable users to separate code from other text by enclosing it within three backticks,

```
//ability to separate text from code in string start and ends with three backticks and displaying that in separated box as this text is displayed
```

and have it displayed in a separate box to make it more visually distinct. This is a widely used feature on many platforms, and I believe it would enhance the user experience of my app. Despite searching online, I have not been able to find any resources on how to implement this feature. Can you provide guidance on how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would need a special character to mark the begging and the end of a code snippet, just like ``` is on Stack Overflow. So I would use `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` to find position of the characters that mark the begging and the end, and then I would simply change the font, font color and the background color of that part of the string using `SpannableString`.

[You can read more about SpannableString here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString)

Comment: thank you for your answer but, it would be just color and font color change, i want it to be scrollable also just like the above text in Stackoverflow.